# Compare Last Line of File to String in Python

Tags: python, intel, bootloader

I'm a Python noob, and am trying to write a script to take two Intel hex files (one for my application code, one for a bootloader), strip the EOF record out of the first one, append the second file to the stripped version of the first, and save as a new file. I've got everything working, but then decided to get fancier: I want to ensure that the last line of the first file truly matches the Intel EOF record format. I can't seem to get the syntax for this conditional down correctly, though.

```
appFile = open("MyAppFile.hex", "r")
lines = appFile.readlines()
appFile.close()

appStrip = open("MyAppFile and BootFile.hex",'w')

if appStrip.readline[:] == ":00000001FF":  #Python complains about "builtin_function_or_method" not subscriptable here
    appStrip.writelines([item for item in lines[:-1]])
    appStrip.close()
else:
    print("No EOF record in last line. File may be corrupted.")

appFile = open("MyAppFile and BootFile", "r")
appObcode = appFile.read()
appFile.close()

bootFile = open("MyBootFile", "r")
bootObcode = bootFile.read()
bootFile.close()

comboData = appObcode + bootObcode

comboFile = open("MyAppFile and BootFile", "w")
comboFile.write(comboData)
comboFile.close()
```

Any other suggestions for a cleaner or safer version of this are welcome, too.

UPDATE:
Added a line to print the last line; I am getting the expected output, but the comparison still fails every time. Here is current full program:

```
appFile = open("C:/LightLock/Master/Project/Debug/Exe/Light Lock.hex")

appLines = appFile.readlines()

appFile = open("MyAppFile.hex").read()

EOF = appLines[len(appLines)-1]

print(appLines[len(appLines)-1])

if not EOF == (":00000001FF"):
    print("No EOF record in last line of file. File may be corrupted.")
else:
    with open("MyAppFile Plus Boot", "a") as appStrip:
        appStrip.writelines([item for item in appLines[:-1]])

    with open("MyAppFile Plus Boot.hex", "r") as appFile:
        appObcode = appFile.read()

    with open("MyBootFile.hex", "r") as bootFile:
        bootObcode = bootFile.read()

    comboData = appObcode + bootObcode

    with open("MyAppFile Plus Boot.hex", "w") as comboFile:
        comboFile.write(comboData)
```

UPDATE2:
Tried modifying the check to include a carriage return and line feed like so:

```
EOF = appLines[len(appLines)-1]

print(EOF)

if EOF != (":00000001FF","\r","\n"):
    print("No EOF record in last line of file. File may be corrupted.")
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Maybe you have extra whitespace or non-printable characters in there? Try to print `repr(EOF)` instead of the line itself, this will give you the exact string representation. If it's whitespace, just call `strip` on EOF to remove it. Also, your comparison with the \r\n doesn't do what you think, you're comparing your variable EOF to a three-element tuple consisting of three strings :)

Comment: Thanks, just arrived at the same conclusion myself. Good tip on `print repr(EOF)`; I will keep that in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version :

```
app = open("app.hex").read()
if not app.endswith(":00000001FF"):
   print("No EOF")
combo = open("combo.hex","w")
combo.write(app)
boot = open("boot.hex").read()
combo.write(boot)
combo.close() # it's automatic after program ended
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't QUITE seem to work: I get the error message whether the string is at the end of the file or not. Here mine (slightly different): appLines = open("MyAppFile").read() if not appLines.endswith(":00000001FF"): print("No EOF record in last line of file. File may be corrupted.")

Comment: Is it possible this is because there's a carriage return or something in the line that I can't see, and because I"m not checking for it its never true?

Comment: Tried this with the same result (check always fails): `appFile = open("C:/MyApp.hex") appLines = appFile.readlines() EOF = appLines[len(appLines)-1] if not EOF == (":00000001FF"): print("No EOF record in last line of file. File may be corrupted.")`

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out: I wrote some test code to output the length of the string that Python was reading. Turns out it was 12 chars, though only 11 were displayed. So I knew one of the "invisible" chars must be the carriage return or line feed. Tried both; turned out to be line feed (new line).

Here's the final (working, but "unoptimized") code:

```
appFile = open("MyAppFile.hex")

appLines = appFile.readlines()

appFile = open("MyAppFile.hex").read()

EOF = appLines[len(appLines)-1]

if EOF != (":00000001FF\n"):
    print("No EOF record in last line of file. File may be corrupted.")
else:
    with open("MyAppFile and Boot.hex", "a") as appStrip:
        appStrip.writelines([item for item in appLines[:-1]])

    with open("MyAppFile and Boot.hex", "r") as appFile:
        appObcode = appFile.read()

    with open("MyBootFile.hex", "r") as bootFile:
        bootObcode = bootFile.read()

    comboData = appObcode + bootObcode

    with open("MyAppFile and Boot.hex", "w") as comboFile:
        comboFile.write(comboData)
```